# What would be the best design for this user types system in a Rails app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database-design, roles

This is being more difficult than I thought: I am building a system in which users can have two roles: Sellers and Buyers. The architecture must meet this requirements:

- A user must be at least one of them, or both. The most common case will of course be Buyer.
- Each user type has its own profile, with different sets of fields
- When a user registers, one of either profiles must also be created and associated to it.
- Users will have different actions available depending on their type of profile.

I have considered different design patterns but I am not good at databases design, so I am nit sure which one to apply or how. I've already discarded STI, so I think the solution must be some kind of user has_many :profiles & buyer/seller belongs_to :user. But I am not sure if I should use polymorphism, through, or other kind of relationship.

Comment: Sounds like you need to hire yourself a Rails developer. The ongoing development and refactoring is going to be harder than the initial design. So if this part is difficult for you to get going with, that may be a sign that the project is a little too big for you.

Comment: Well, I've already worked in a few rails projects before.This one is pretty straightforward and very similar to another one I did before, so I think that with a bit of help for some of the more complex parts, and lots of hard work, I can manage. It's the only way to get better, isn´t it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've built some applications that have similar requirements.  I believe the best solution that would meet your requirements is `has_many :through`.

```
class Person < ActiveRecord
  has_many :assignments
  has_many :roles, :through => :assignments
end

class Assignment < ActiveRecord
  belongs_to :person
  belongs_to :role
end

class Role < ActiveRecord
  has_many :assignments
  has_many :people, :through => :assignments

  validates :name, :presence => true

  delegates :profile, :to => :assignment
end
```

Database:

```
 people
   |-- first_name, :string
   |-- last_name, :string

 assignments
   |-- person_id, :integer
   |-- role_id, :integer
   |-- profile, :text

 roles
   |-- name, :string
```

Comment: So you wouldnt use Buyer and Seller models?

Comment: The profile for each role and the need to have a profile leads me to this design.  I considered do it in all in the people model but I thought it was too messy.